# Iterating through a const char

Tags: c, constants

In C if I wanted to iterate through the array and get the ascii value of each letter would I do it by

```
const char array[] = "name"
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s", array['i']);}
```

I am still unfamiliar with C and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Whoops, meant to put 'i' in there instead of '0'. Will change to %c though

Comment: @HAL9000 yes that is what I am trying to do thank you.

Comment: Use `"%d "` for the format string (note the space). Use `array[i]` instead of `array['0']`. Check for a missing semicolon.

Comment: @John When you see a typo, click [edit] to make changes to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%s` means "print a string" so that's not what you want. If you want the ascii value in decimal use `%d` or `%u`. If you want the ascii value in hex use `%x`.

Also notice that the indexing is `array[i]`

Further, use `strlen` instead of a hard coded 4. By doing that you can change "name" to "WhatEver" without having to change the loop condition as well.

Like:

```
const char array[] = "name";
for (size_t len = strlen(name), i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
} 
puts("");
```

Comment: You should check what your compiler does, but without optimization, it will probably call `strlen()` on each iteration, which gives you quadratic behaviour for the loop.  Even with optimization, it may do that (though for simple cases, especially with a constant string, it may avoid the repeated calls).  In general, you should consider `for (size_t len = strlen(name), i = 0; i < len; i++)` as the loop control, ensuring that `strlen()` is called just once.